# How to combine two arrays without overwriting the keys

Tags: php

I am having two arrays with the same key . How can I combine those two arrays without overwriting the keys of first array.

I tried using `array_merge()` function , `+` operation

These are the two arrays:

```
Array ( [1] => 1 ) Array ( [1] => 0 )
```

I want the output to be like

```
array( [1] => 1 , [1] => 0)
```

Comment: you cant have duplicate keys in array

Comment: Output can't be `array( [1] => 1 , [1] => 0)` - you can't have two same keys (1) in your array.

Comment: Your expected output is impossible, 2 rows in your array cannot contain the same key. Tell me, if you want that output, how would you retrieve the value of the 2nd row?

Comment: in a single dimensional array  2 or more keys cannot be same. See here:-https://3v4l.org/fevRo

Comment: Fifth times a charm... ***You can't have an array with the same keys...*** In all seriousness, consider having nested arrays and then you can have the same keys: `[ 0 => [ 1 => 1 ], 1 => [ 1 => 1 ] ]` and then you'd go `$arr[0][1]` or `$arr[1][1]`.

Comment: This is obviously an XY problem. Explain *why* you want to have an array with duplicate keys and it is likely that someone here can explain the proper way to solve the problem.

Comment: You can't have multiple same keys, but you can definitely have multiple values for a key since you want to preserve them.

Comment: Has anyone mentioned that array keys must be unique???

Answer (score 0):

You can't have duplicate keys in an array.

What you can do is build an array of object with different keys: 0,1,2,3,4,etc. but with sub objects which will make access to the same object property.

```
// for istance in this case you end up having an array 
// with 5 objects with a property named "key" with a value
$arrayOfObjects = [];
$arrayOfObjects[] = (object)["key"=>"value0"];
$arrayOfObjects[] = (object)["key"=>"value1"];
$arrayOfObjects[] = (object)["key"=>"value2"];
$arrayOfObjects[] = (object)["key"=>"value3"];
$arrayOfObjects[] = (object)["key"=>"value4"];
// to return the value $arrayOfObjects[4]->key
```

Comment: Why not just a simple array of arrays?

Comment: From his post i assumed he needed a "constant" key to access, with a variable value. Using array of arrays would require 2 Dynamic indexes, which would be against his "concept". That's just an assumption i made while reading it